# Sometime orientation is not working properly in iphone

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, orientation, livekit

I'm encountering a problem with the orientation of my flutter video calling app during a video call. The entire app is set to portrait mode, except for the video call view page. When entering the video call view, the app allows both landscape and portrait orientations. However, when leaving the video call page while it's in landscape mode(in Iphone), I have code to force it back to portrait mode.

Now again when I start video call (video call screen) and try to turn to landscape, then the app view doesn't change to landscape but the other party(video call members) can see my video in landscape.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Make whole app in portrait
2. navigate to that second screen that allows both landscape and portrait
3. Turn iPhone to landscape (Make sure to turn on iphone orientation)
4. In dispose method of this screen, Set force back to portrait mode.
5. Try to dispose this screen while in landscape mode
6. again navigate to the second screen and try to rotate to landscape